# place UIView behind UILabel programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout

I want to ask. I want to make a UIView behind uilabel, I`m creating segmented Controll from collectionview right now. how can I make uiview behind uilabel?
this is my code

```
nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
            ])

        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
        backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(backgroundView)
        insertSubview(backgroundView, aboveSubview: nameLabel)
        backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        backgroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with the @Vacawama answer, or you should notice that Apple provides 2 API like:

```
func sendSubviewToBack(_ view: UIView)
```

and

```
func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: UIView)
```

So you can deal with your view hierarchy programmatically.

Maybe you can try to move the backgroundView above the label in your storyboard, so you can have it behind (as it's first in, first out in the storyboard).

Or use `sendSubviewToBack(backgroundView)`.

Or use `bringSubviewToFront(nameLabel)`.

Or `view.addSubview(backgroundView)` then `view.addSubview(nameLabel)`.

Answer (score 3):

Views are added back to front.  Just `addSubview(backgroundView)` before `addSubview(newLabel)`.

Something like this should work:

```
let backgroundView = UIView()
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(backgroundView)
nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(nameLabel)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
    nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
    nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
    nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
    backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.leadingAnchor),
    backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor),
    backgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
    backgroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48)
])
```